# Is it possible to override a native method in a Java class in Android/dalvik?

Tags: java, android, overriding, easymock, native-methods

I am unit testing a class `TestMe` using EasyMock, and one of its methods (say `method(N n)`) expects a parameter of type `N` which has a native method (say `nativeMethod()`).

```
class TestMe {
    void method(N n) {
        // Do stuff

        n.nativeMethod();

        // Do more stuff
    }
}
```

`method()` needs to invoke `N.nativeMethod()` at some point, and the problem I'm having is that my Easymock mock object for N is unable to override the native method. I do not own class N but I can refactor `TestMe` in any way necessary.

I decided to make my own class `FakeN extends N` which overrides `nativeMethod` to do nothing:

```
class FakeN extends N {
    FakeN(int pointer) {
        super(pointer);
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeMethod(Object o) {
        // super.nativeMethod() is an actual native method defined as:
        // public native void nativeMethod(Object o)
        //
        // IGNORE
    }
}
```

but while the compiler does not complain, when I run the test it appears that `N.nativeMethod()` is the one being invoked and not `FakeN`s version.

Is there a workaround here that I can use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `native` methods can be overridden just like any other methods, unless they are declared `final`. Just be sure that you're calling `TestMe.method(N n)` with an instance of `FakeN`.

Comment: That's what I thought from comments on [this page](http://www.coderanch.com/t/380733/java/java/Overriding-Native-Method-java-io) but it didn't seem to work. I'll go back and check to see if I messed something up.

Comment: Turns out that native methods can be overridden by non-native, and vice-versa too. `native` appears to not be a part of the signature.